# Table pagination using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I want to have table pagination on my table, but i don't want to use Datatables at all.

Here's what i have so far:

```
<section id="processes" class="center">
            <i id="export_icon" class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i><a id="export_link" href="#"> Export to Excel</a>
            <table id="table_processes" class="table-hover">
                <tr id="table_processes_row">
                    <th data-field="status">Status</th>
                    <th data-field="id">ID</th>
                    <th data-field="pid">PID</th>
                    <th data-field="process_name">Process Name</th>
                    <th data-field="description">Description</th>
                    <th data-field="application">Application</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table_processes_row">
                    <td><i id="flag_active" class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1323213</td>
                    <td>sme</td>
                    <td>Process Instance has been created.</td>
                    <td>App</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table_processes_row">
                    <td><i id="flag_inactive" class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1323213</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Process Instance has been started.</td>
                    <td>App</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table_processes_row">
                    <td><i id="flag_active" class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1323213</td>
                    <td>Process Name</td>
                    <td>Process running.</td>
                    <td>App</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table_processes_row">
                    <td><i id="flag_inactive" class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1323213</td>
                    <td>sss Name</td>
                    <td>Process Instance has ended.</td>
                    <td>App</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="pull-right">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous"> <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" aria-label="Next"> <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </section>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#flag_active {
    color: green;
}

#flag_inactive {
    color: red;
}

#table_processes_row {
    height: 40px;
    border-top: .12em solid #A9A9A9;
}

td {
    border-top: .12em solid #ddd;
}

th {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    text-align: center;
}

#table_processes {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#table_filters{
    margin-top:15px;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#table_filters td{
    padding-left:20px;
}

#table_filters input{
    height:30px;
    width: 140px;
}

#status_comboBox{
    height:30px;
    width: 140px;
}

#status_comboBox option{
    width:100px;
}

#records_comboBox{
    height:30px;
    width: 60px;
}


#records_comboBox option{
    width:100px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcarou/804jeg82/559/)

Basically i have the base code for all the pagination. However i don't have any clue on how to make it work properly. I really don't want to use datatables.

How can i do this?

Comment: Depends on how you want it to paginate. you could have all the HTML on the page and only show the once you want to begin with and hide the rest. then as the user clicks on the pagination you hide and show. A bit like a carousel. There are plenty of jquery carousels out there you can try - i have found this one to be quite good http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: Yeah, something like is exactly what i want! @Andrew If you could write a quick answer on that, it would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v created some custom javascript to handle the pagination. I am hiding/showing the correct tablerows based on the active page. all `tr` now have a new attribute `data-show` which will be hiden of shown based on the active page. This function is called by clicking on a link inside the pagination, this will trigger the correct `tr`. This is just a very basic function and needs improvement but something like this works well.

```
  var activepage = 1;

  function paginate(showpageId) {
    activepage = showpageId;
    $('#table_processes tr:not(.headerrow)').hide();
    $('#table_processes').find('tr[data-show="page'+activepage+'"]').show();
  }
  paginate(1);

  $('.pagination li a').click(function() {
    paginate($(this).data('link'));
  });
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/586/)

Comment: Thanks, it's a start! But there's an issue with your code. If i want, let's say, 10 items per page, then on the pagination list it should only show the one page square

Comment: @laker001, good point. But I supposed you would use PHP to load the data, so you want to create a PHP loop for the rows and pagination which will handle that. Besides that, what you are asking now is another (stackoverflow)question.

Comment: But still, i'v got some spare time, here have this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/586/

Comment: Thanks man!! It still doesn't do what i want, but it's a great start for sure

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please accept it and close the question.